# Python Kivy GridLayout change button background

Tags: python, button, background-image, kivy, grid-layout

So i have this gridLayout containing only custom buttons that are handled in a specific class. I want that when i click on a button in the gridLayout, another button still in the same gridLayout parent changes it's background_normal property.
It there something like this?

```
self.parent[otherButtonCol, otherButtonRow].background_normal = 'image.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is just a simple example for illustration.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyBigButt@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    font_size: "25sp"
    markup: True

<MyWidget>:
    cols: 1
    MyBigButt:
        text: "Change Other Button Background Normal Property"
        on_release: root.ids.btn2.background_normal = "kivymd_logo.png"
    MyBigButt:
        id: btn2
```

### Output

[image: Second Button Background Normal Property Changed]